# I have a message that has appeared on my Nokia X30 5G phone 'Glance app widget error'. How do I remove it?

Tags: android

Glance app widget error
Check the exact error using adb Logcat, searching for GlanceAppWidget

This message has appeared on my home screen and i can't get rid of it.

Have followed the limited instructions but nothing works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.